# How to fix Ambiguity between ' DWORD ' and ' Fibplatforms:: DWORD

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe4, fibplus

I am working with FIBPlus Components in RAD Studio XE4. During compilation I have ambiguity errors. Someone proposed to fix it in this [link](http://www.progtown.com/topic1300578-ambiguity-between-dword-and-fibplatforms-dword.html) but it did not work.

Here are the errors

```
[bcc32 Error] ws2tcpip.h(162): E2015 Ambiguity between 'DWORD' and 'Fibplatforms::DWORD'
  Full parser context
    addsvc.cpp(7): #include dmod.h
    dmod.h(20): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdComponent.hpp
    IdComponent.hpp(21): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdStack.hpp
    IdStack.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdStackConsts.hpp
    IdStackConsts.hpp(17): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdWship6.hpp
    IdWship6.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdWinsock2.hpp
    IdWinsock2.hpp(24): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\sdk\ws2tcpip.h

[bcc32 Error] ws2tcpip.h(163): E2015 Ambiguity between 'DWORD' and 'Fibplatforms::DWORD'
  Full parser context
    addsvc.cpp(7): #include dmod.h
    dmod.h(20): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdComponent.hpp
    IdComponent.hpp(21): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdStack.hpp
    IdStack.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdStackConsts.hpp
    IdStackConsts.hpp(17): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdWship6.hpp
    IdWship6.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\rtl\IdWinsock2.hpp
    IdWinsock2.hpp(24): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\include\windows\sdk\ws2tcpip.h
```

Comment: The [other link](http://www.progtown.com/topic1300578-ambiguity-between-dword-and-fibplatforms-dword.html) already gave you the solution - FIBPlus needs to be updated to declare its `DWORD` alias as `{$EXTERNALSYM}` so it does not exist in the generated HPP anymore (better would be if FIBPlus stopped declaring its own `DWORD` alias at all and instead used Delphi's own `DWORD` alias). What happened when you actually tried that? Indy's `IdWinSock2` unit is expecting to use `DWORD` from the Win32 API, not from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau! I have installed the latest version.